# Raspberry Pi iptables not working without active eth0

Tags: iptables, captive-portal, hostapd

I just work on a AcessPoint, hosted from my Raspberry Pi B+.

When a cable is plugged in on the eth0 adapter it all works fine.
If someone connect to my AP, they will be redirected to the webserver, like a captive portal.
If they want to go to a website, iptables redirect them to the webserver.

But when I start my Raspberry without the cable plugged in, it does not work anymore. The redirecting is broken.
When I plug it back in and restart hostapd, it is working again.

I have no clue why.

Here are my iptable rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to destination 10.0.0.1:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:443
```

They will be added with a script on boot.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.1

sudo echo "options bcmdhd op_mode=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/bcmdhd.conf

sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:443

sudo service dnsmasq restart
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
sudo service hostapd restart
```

My hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
bssid=7c:dd:90:9d:3e:bd
ssid=RaspAP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=3
wmm_enabled=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
country_code=DE
```

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
I haven't to restart hostapd. When I plug the internet cable back in, it works immediatly. Its like, iptables is just running when the cable is plugged in.